# Cannot read property 'module' of undefined

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I have a basic understanding of `Django` and `JS` and recently I started learning `Angular.js`. I wrote code for showing hardcoded `json` using `Angular` and failed. I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined at line 10 of django-angular.js
```

I went through the file and saw this line:

```
var djng_forms_module = angular.module('ng.django.forms', []);
```

I don't know what the error means by undefined. I went through some of the links having similar problems but with no success.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Have you forgotten to load AngularJS before your script? The error means that the object `angular` hasn't been seen by Javascript yet and therefore `module` cannot be called on it.

(that's actually a simplification but it should illustrate what's going on)

Comment: Yes. I have included `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "djangular/js/django-angular.js" %}"></script>` before my `js` code.

Comment: Sure, but have you included `angular.js` (or `angular.min.js`) as well?

Comment: No. But when I included, I got an error which I tried to solve by adding separate module for `ngRoute`. I have included following files: jquery.min.js, angular.min.js, angular.route.js, django-angular.js and script.js.

Comment: What about the error you started this question for, `Cannot read property 'module' of undefined`? Is the order of included scripts OK (are they included in the same order in which you wrote them in your comment)?

Comment: This error has been resolved. Thanks. But I am still stuck at another error.

Answer (score 9):

order matters here

```
<script src="javascripts/lib/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/lib/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-cookies.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.js"></script>
```

you have to put angular.min.js before angular-route.js and angular-cookies.js